# Swift draw an arc for view background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, draw, uibezierpath

I'd like to draw an arc at the bottom of a view like this:

[image]

The background pattern is another matter, but I think this can be done with something like uibezierpath? I haven't had much experience with it, any starter points? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign this custom class to the view in IB

```
class CurveView:UIView {

    var once = true

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if once {

            let bb = UIBezierPath()

            bb.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.height))

            // the offset here is 40 you can play with it to increase / decrease the curve height

            bb.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 , y: self.frame.height + 40 ))

            bb.close()

            let l = CAShapeLayer()

            l.path = bb.cgPath

            l.fillColor =  self.backgroundColor!.cgColor

            self.layer.insertSublayer(l,at:0)

            once = false
        }

    }

}
```

//

[image]